# Angular 2+ - After successful Login, change my Login component in Header to User Account Component

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I am building an Angular2+ App. Started learning angular 1 week back.

Following is the structure
-index.html
    - AppComponent(app-root)
       - Header Component(header)
          - Signup Component(signup)

SignupComponent is a Modal.

After a successful login, I want to replace my Signup Account with User Component(which should be drop down menu with multiple links - (Account link, Logout link) ).

The solution which I thought was that on a successful login, I should emit the event to Header component from Signup Component.

On receiving the event , Header component should switch to UserComponent and hide the Signup Component Div.

User Component should have a Auth Gaurd because the links in drop down should be protected.

I have few questions

- How should I route from Signup Modal to index.html with changes needed? - Do I need to refresh the index.html where it will load the account component? How should I route to index.html which should have the new User component in place of signup component. ?
- Is this a right approach?  If not,what is the ideal way to do this in angular 2+?

Comment: Your question is confusing to answer. Please share your project through GitHub or something similar to get better answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am writing these tips for angular 4.3. Firstly i will suggest not to put your html into index.html file, its not a right approach. APP component is the main component where you can put all html there. Now except the header (login/logout links should be here) and footer remove other html and use **router-outlet** to build a single page application.

I suppose you already have a login/SignIn component and a login/SignIn service. Firstly set a variable in login service and mark it false in constructor. Now you need to change value of this variable on login and logout operation.

After that need to call login service into app component and initialize it in constructor.

Finally in app component html where you have login/logout links, use **ngIf** to show/hide those links with login service variable.

My code is something like below.

**Login Service**

```
export class LoginService{
    isloggedin : boolean;
    constructor(private _http: Http){
        this.isloggedin = false;
    }
```

**App Component HTML**

```
<li *ngIf="!loginService.isloggedin"> <a routerLink="login">Login</a> </li>
<li *ngIf="!loginService.isloggedin"> <a routerLink="register">Register</a> </li>
<li *ngIf="loginService.isloggedin"> <a routerLink="logout">Logout</a> </li>
```

**App Component**

```
import { LoginService } from './login.service';

export class AppComponent {
constructor(private loginService: LoginService){
}
```

After logout i simply clear localstorage and set isloggedin to false;

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on Angular routes : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html

And ngIF directive : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#ngIf

You can create some boolean value responsible for keeping information about what to show e.g isClientLogged = true/false. Then use ngIf statement to show what do you want. If you want to redirect some part of your page to another use Angular routes.

Comment: Hi Patryk, thanks for the response. But I already mentioned this approach in my question. I wanted to know if this approach is right and if not what are the other approaches.

Comment: But you emmit event on my method you just create simply variable which is response for displaying or not the content.